# Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: window, virtual-machine

I am planning to install VirtualBox to try out newer operating systems and tools.

Is it safe to install on office computer. Basically below are my questions.

1. Does VirtualBox consume lot of resources and slow down the system.
2. Is the installation heavy weight.
3. Is it easy to uninstall.
4. Does running a virtual PC (windows 8.1) on a Windows7 (host) pc has any issues?
5. How is the performance of the virtual OS (windows 8.1 in this case) compared to like a dual boot setup?
6. Are there any free better options than VirtualBox?

Memory is not an issue as I will be able to spare atleast 30gb for virtual box installation.

Really would appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the gist:

Pro's:

- Not too heavy to install(102MB installer)
- Easy to setup
- Easy to administer
- Supports lots of OS's, up through Windows 10 (10 is slow)
- Light performance hit for modern hardware
- Easy to uninstall

Cons:

- Company's computer (is that okay with them?)
- Installs a network adapter (needs admin privilege)
- Some performance hit (depends on hardware)

On my Athlon Phenom II X4 (made in 2011), with 8GB of RAM and 2 HDD's in RAID, with Radeon card, every OS I've tried runs smooth, except for Windows 10. You'll have to turn down (or off) translucent window borders and backgrounds, maybe, but that's it.

Windows 7 and 8 are as smooth as butter, but transparency is off. If you have a new Core I7 machine with buckets of RAM, you shouldn't have a problem.

Linux, FreeBSD, XP, even DOS and Win3 run in there with no problems.

Windows 8.1 Guest, under my Windows 7 Host worked just fine. Possibly turn a few bells and whistles off, but should work fine. I always use a Bridged connection, so the VM has its own IP address on my LAN. Windows 10 is slow at this point. I'm sure they'll address it soon.

Hope this helps.